# When compiling a Rust library with C++ extensions in debug mode, is the C++ code compiled with debug flags too?

Tags: c++, rust, debug-information

I have a Rust project with lot of C++ under the hood, that's built the usual way (I link the c++ files with `cc:Build::new()` and generate individual bindings to a C API with `bindgen::Builder::default()`).

I'm trying to understand the source of performance degradation when I build the project with a profile that extends `release` but has `debug=True`. Two questions:

1. Is this profile causing the C++ library to be compiled with debug flags, and if so, what level? I would assume default?
2. If I wanted to use `split-debuginfo` (haven't yet figured out what the right way to do this is), AND if the answer to 1. is "no", how would I go about ensuring that the executable with the debug info does have debug flags for the C++ library, while the release executable does not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither `cc::Build::new()` nor `bindgen::Builder::default()` read the environment, they both compile and generate everything the same no matter which optimization level you specify (or which profile debug vs release) you build in.

To build with debuginfo on debug and without it on release you have to check the relevant [environment variables](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/environment-variables.html#environment-variables-cargo-sets-for-build-scripts) (`OPT_LEVEL` and `DEBUG` sepecifically) and include the respectively necessary flags for `cc`.

Comment: Got it, thank you. Do you have a suggestion for something to read on how to simultaneously split debug symbols for the C++ extensions? Docs seem to be sparing or at least hard-to-find.